# Identify contiguous time intervals in an R dataframe

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, geospatial

Probably I will need to change the title, but I lack the language to express concisely the problem.

I have a big data frame with the following structure:

```
class(df)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"

df

           coordinates   ID      group_id value1    time    zone
1  (9.09077, 45.47737) 24739        1      70 1505480403      62
2  (9.24016, 45.50221) 62965        1      35 1505480403      19
3  (9.22375, 45.50891) 93104        1      86 1505480403      16
4  (9.24392, 45.51171) 35646        1      80 1505480403      17
5  (9.24326, 45.51349) 24747        1      80 1505480403      17
6  (9.12738, 45.46933) 44274        1      53 1505480403      60
7  (9.25434, 45.45346) 53579        1      99 1505480403      30
8  (9.20306, 45.42118) 74565        1      37 1505480403      38
9   (9.1183, 45.45458) 74521        1      79 1505480403      53
10 (9.14386, 45.44674) 53584        1      62 1505480403      49
11 (9.14961, 45.51675) 44283        1      80 1505480403      81
12 (9.20478, 45.50888) 62936        1      50 1505480403      13
13   (9.20352, 45.421) 87311        1      80 1505480403      38
14 (9.11081, 45.49871) 43467        1      80 1505480403      65
15 (9.25292, 45.51276) 93101        1      41 1505480403      17
16 (9.08882, 45.45794) 53507        1      26 1505480403      55
17  (9.2071, 45.50587) 53522        1      80 1505480403      13
18 (9.22379, 45.50888) 87372        1      80 1505480403      16
19 (9.24388, 45.50456) 87332        1      21 1505480403      19
20 (9.20917, 45.51816) 47710        1      69 1505480403      15
21 (9.12292, 45.50486) 06213        1      83 1505480403      72
22 (9.21751, 45.51149) 35633        1      80 1505480403      16
23 (8.85098, 45.60636) 35632        1      70 1505480403     N/A
24 (9.08967, 45.46126) 79065        1      29 1505480403      55
25  (9.11043, 45.4958) 72813        1      80 1505480403      65
26 (9.14425, 45.44787) 06221        1      53 1505480403      49
27 (9.21566, 45.51105) 06286        1      81 1505480403      16
28 (9.15909, 45.52463) 53547        1      22 1505480403      82
29  (9.1357, 45.45472) 74513        1      85 1505480403      52
30 (8.85068, 45.60646) 62949        1      80 1505480403     N/A
31 (9.20874, 45.42597) 06296        1      20 1505480403      38
32  (9.1992, 45.51189) 62972        1      84 1505480403      14
33 (9.15462, 45.51798) 43496        1      52 1505480403      81
34 (9.08816, 45.47548) 87351        1      21 1505480403      62
35 (9.13154, 45.43608) 93106        1      50 1505480403      48
36 (9.14139, 45.44461) 14879        1      29 1505480403      48
37 (9.19553, 45.44263) 43464        1      78 1505480403      37
38 (9.14361, 45.48266) 87371        1      80 1505480403      58
39 (9.13611, 45.46989) 36099        1      91 1505480403      57
40 (9.22385, 45.50939) 53590        1      94 1505480403      16
41 (9.08562, 45.45992) 75494        1      40 1505480403      55
42 (9.20702, 45.52272) 24709        1      44 1505480403      14
43 (9.23615, 45.50845) 53577        1      31 1505480403      16
44 (9.08801, 45.47528) 24766        1      64 1505480403      62
45 (9.24426, 45.51104) 62975        1      80 1505480403      17
46  (9.2403, 45.50226) 62965        1      35 1505476803      19
47 (9.22376, 45.50896) 93104        1      86 1505476803      16
48 (9.09076, 45.47738) 24739        1      70 1505476803      62
49 (9.24405, 45.51173) 35646        1      80 1505476803      17
50 (9.24327, 45.51344) 24747        1      80 1505476803      17
106 (9.22914, 45.45137) 30907       1      89 1505376003      29
112 (9.22917, 45.45136) 30907       1      89 1505372403      29
118 (9.2291, 45.45126) 30907        1      89 1505368803      29
124 (9.22917, 45.45137) 30907       1      89 1505365203      29
130 (9.22918, 45.4514) 30907        1      89 1505361603      29
```

As you can see in the last lines it happens frequently that an observation happens in the same point(or its vicinities), with the same sensor in consecutive probes. 
Is there a way to transform the dataset to have a start_time (taking the time of the first observation in the point) and a end_time (taking the time of the last observation in the point +60min)?

The dataset has over 675000 observations, but lots of them are "groupable"
These are gps sensors on moving veichles, I gather info every hour from them, it happens that the veichles keep the same position through multiple observations. What I want to do is, for every groups of observations (same id, same position in a few meters range, contiguous times) generate a new dataframe where, if the observation is "single" it has `start_time = time, end_time = time +60min` if, on the other side, there are several observations that can be grouped (as in the lines 106-130 in the example above) it should have `start_time = time of the first observation (1505376003 taking the aformentioned example), end_time = time of the last observation +60min (1505361603 +60min)`

EDIT2: I was able to identify (using a subset with only one "ID") if time intervals are consecutive (still can't grasp why the difference is in seconds and not in hours) `c(NA,diff(round(as_datetime(df$time), units="hours"))==-3600)`

I tried looking through various sources to no avail.

Thank you

Comment: I think you have a few too many moving parts on this question.  I tried asking the question terms of time groupings here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249312/grouping-by-buckets-of-time  (something I couldn't personally solve but surely someone else can). We can generalise it to the time + coordinate groupings afterwards.

Comment: By the way, I'm not familiar with that time format.  What is it?

Comment: it's a unix timestamp

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375959/how-to-group-sequential-event-time-sequences-with-breaks-between-events-to-fin) seems useful

Answer (score 0):

arrange the DF by time`tmp <- arrange(df, time)`

create an index to identify the "time clusters" for each ID (I convert the linux to datetime and round it to the closer full hour)

```
run <- ddply(tmp, .(ID), transform, run=cumsum(c(1, diff(round(as_datetime(time), units="hours"))!=1)))
```

I wrap it up, assigning to the first and last occurences of the group the values that could have changed (you can choose to use the mean,median or other functions)

```
final <- ddply(run, .(ID, run), summarize, group_id=first(group_id), longs=first(longs), lats=first(lats), zone=first(zone), value1_start=first(value1), value1_end=last(value1), start_event=first(time), end_event=last(time))
```

The result is nice and neat

```
coordinates   ID run group_id zone value1_start value1_end start_event  end_event
1 (9.22888, 45.52752) 30907   1        1     N/A            54          54  1496872804 1496872804
2  (9.2289, 45.52752) 30907   2        1     N/A            52          52  1496959205 1496959205
3 (9.20471, 45.47467) 30907   3        1       3            91          91  1497006004 1497006004
4 (9.20394, 45.46005) 30907   4        1       4            85          85  1497013203 1497016805
5 (9.22661, 45.48286) 30907   5        1      22            71          69  1497369603 1497387604
6 (9.22701, 45.47922) 30907   6        1      22            91          91  1497412804 1497412804
```