# How do I find ranges of successive numbers in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector in R:

```
data <- c(1,4,6,7,8,9,20,30,31,32,33,34,35,60)
```

What I want is to find the start and end of a successive stretch longer than 3 successive values. i.e.:

```
start end
3  6  (stretch 6-9)
8 13 (stretch 30-35
```

I have no clue how to get there.

Comment: maybe if you look at `rle()` and the lagged difference. If they are sequential values, the lagged difference will be 1. Look for sequences of 1's in this using `rle()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [@eddi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800919/1191259) to my similar question...

```
runs = split(seq_along(data), cumsum(c(0, diff(data) > 1)))
lapply(runs[lengths(runs) > 1], range)

# $`2`
# [1] 3 6
# 
# $`4`
# [1]  8 13
```

*How it works*:

- `seq_along(data)` are the indices of `data`, from 1..length(data)
- `c(0, diff(data) > 1)` is has a 1 at each index where `data` "jumps"
- `cumsum(c(0, diff(data) > 1))` is an identifier for consecutive runs between jumps

So `runs` is a division of `data`'s indices into runs where `data`'s values are consecutive.

Comment: this is a great answer, if a little subtle without an accompanying explanation

Comment: To make it look like OP desired output, you could do something like: `df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(runs[lengths(runs) > 1], range))); names(df) <- c("start","end")`, although the desired output is not clearly specified

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A matlab colleague came up with something similar in one of the matlab fora.
http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86420-find-a-series-of-consecutive-numbers-in-a-vector?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: @user1712989 Cool. I learned matlab a long time before r, so I guess it might still influence my approach :)

Answer (score 0):

So, first take the `diff` of a and do a run length sequence on it. Then, the starting points are the index before the 2s and the ending points are the negative differences of those... it's hard to explain, just step through the code and check it out. This does not find sequences of two... like (3,4) in (1, 3, 4, 7, 9). I had to include the `remove` part for sequences that were off by two... (1, 3, 5, 7). Those weren't caught correctly. Any how, fun exercise. I hope somebody can do better. This is a bit of a mess...

```
data <- c(1,4,6,7,8,9,20,30,31,32,33,34,35,60)
a <- sequence(rle(diff(data))$lengths)
starts <- which(a==2) - 1
ends <- which(diff(a)<0) + 1
remove <- starts[starts %in% (ends-2)]
starts <- starts[!starts %in% remove]
ends <- ends[!ends %in% (remove+2)]
if(length(ends) < length(starts)) ends <- c(ends, length(data))
> starts
[1] 3 8
> ends
[1]  6 13
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution relying heavily on `?diff`:

```
data <- c(1,4,6,7,8,9,20,30,31,32,33,34,35,60)

diff1 <- diff(data[1:(length(data)-1)]) # lag 1 difference
diff2 <- diff(data, 2) # lag 2 difference

# indices of starting consecutive stretches -- these will overlap
start_index <- which(diff1==1 & diff2==2)
end_index <- start_index + 2

# notice that these overlap:
data.frame(start_index, end_index)

# To remove overlap:
# We can remove *subsequent* consecutive start indices
#           and *initial* consecutive end indices

start_index_new <- start_index[which(c(0, diff(start_index))!=1)]
end_index_new <- end_index[which(c(diff(end_index), 0) != 1)]
data.frame(start_index_new, end_index_new)

#   start_index_new end_index_new
# 1               3             6
# 2               8            13
```

Cory's answer is great -- this one might just be a little easier to understand because you're basically checking for cases where, from position `i`, position `i+1` has a value of 1 more and position `i + 2` has a value of 2 more.  You build ranges off of this and then consolidate your ranges with another `diff` function.  To my thinking this is a bit simpler.

There also are packages you can use like `zoo` that can help you get rolling differences.